# How do I send a random Image from a google search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm VERY new to JavaScript (Started last week), and I couldn't find a working answer.
How does one exactly send a random image with a keyword from Google Images to a Discord Channel?

Here's my code so far:

```
const GoogleImages = require('google-images');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const client2 = new GoogleImages('', '');
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});
client2.search('Riolu Pokemon')
  .then(images => {});
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'more riolu') {
    return message.channel.send(images);
  }
});
client.login('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
const GoogleImages = require("google-images");
const { Client, Attachment } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client;
const googleImages = new GoogleImages("", "");

async function onMessage(message) {
  if (message.content !== "more riolu") return;
  try {
    const results = await googleImages.search("Riolu Pokemon");
    const reply = !results.length ?
      "No results" :
      new Attachment(results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)].url);
    message.channel.send(reply);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    message.channel.send("Error happened, see the console");
  }
}

client
  .on("ready", () => console.log("I am ready!"))
  .on("message", onMessage)
  .login("");
```